# Is it possible to create a freemium subscription HTML app?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

In the past I've created native Android apps with in-app purchases and I know how relatively easy it is to query the Play Store to determine if a user has purchased an in-store item.

I'm looking to build another app but I would like to use freemium model in which a yearly subscription is paid for extra features. I would also like to make it using jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap so I can publish with the same codebase to iOS.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to query Google Play (and the Apple App Store) to determine if a user has an active subscription using jQuery/PhoneGap?
2. Any caveats to this approach that I should know about before embarking on creating a hybrid app vs. just biting the bullet and creating two native apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to query GP or App Store using PhoneGap. 
You will need a native plugin to do that. One for App Store you have here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager

And here another for GP: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/InAppBilling

Answering to the second question: In my opinion based on experience if you are going to use more than one platform based feature it is easier to make two native apps than stuffing html app with plugins.

Comment: Thanks! It would all be the same except for the IAP checking, and maybe simple stuff like notifications. Do you have experience using these plugins? Is this the kind of stuff you spend hours debugging?